# Concatenar varios csv en uno solo

Tags: python, csv

tengo el siguiente código para concatenar varios csvs en uno sólo separándo cada uno por una fila en blanco en el csv final. Pero sólo es capaz de coger el primer csv sin repetir la misma acción con el resto. ¿alguna idea de cómo podría solucionarlo? gracias de ante mano.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


    import pandas as pd
    import glob, os
    import shutil

    #import csv files from folder
    path = r'/Users/sonia/Animalsmanage/output'
    allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

    with open('finaloutput.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
        for i, fname in enumerate(allFiles):
            with open(fname, 'rb') as infile:
                if i != 0:
                    infile.readline()
                    outfile.write(bytearray('\n'))  
                shutil.copyfileobj(infile, outfile)
                print(fname + " has been imported.")
```

Comment: Entiendo que lo de `if i !=0` es para saltarse la primera línea de todos los CSV salvo el primero. He probado a ejecutar tu ejemplo y me funciona, salvo por un cambio que he tenido que hacer `bytearray('\n')` lo cambié por `b'\n'` (pues me generaba una excepción).

Comment: Sonia el código funciona sin problemas en Python 2.x y falla en Python 3.x por falta de un encoding explícito en la cadena pasada a `bytearray` como comenta abulafia (`outfile.write(b'\n')` hace el código portable a ambas versiones.). Si quieres añadir una línea en blanco entre csv debes agregar dos saltos de línea (`b'\n\n'`). En cuanto a tu problema, ¿`glob.glob` retorna las rutas de todos los ficheros que deseas o no? Si no es así asegúrate que el nombre de los ficheros concuerdan con el patrón.  Intenta dar más información porque no es posible reproducir el problema. Un saludo

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! simplemente con el cambio a `b'\n'` ya ha funcionado en Python 3.x

Comment: @abulafia `if i !=0` en principio si que es lo que debería de hacer porque no quiero que incluya los headers, aunque cuando lo ejecuto se salta la primera y la segunda no se porque